# Scala Skinny ORM - Obligatory Relation

Tags: scala, orm

**belongsTo relationship obligatory**

I don't want to define typeWine as an optional value, but if i don't put it, I have to declare typeWine in the extract method and I don't know how to do that.

In the documentacion of Skinny ORM, it doesn't describe how to do this, and I'm getting stuck.

```
package app.models.wine

import scalikejdbc._
import skinny.orm.SkinnyCRUDMapper

case class Wine (id: Option[Long], typeWine: Option[Type] = None, name: String)

object Wine extends SkinnyCRUDMapper[Wine] {  
  override def defaultAlias = createAlias("w")
  override def extract (rs: WrappedResultSet, n: ResultName[Wine]): Wine = new Wine(
    id = rs.get(n.id),
    name = rs.get(n.name)
  )
  belongsTo[Type](Type, (w, t) => w.copy(typeWine = t)).byDefault
}  


package app.models.wine

import scalikejdbc._
import skinny.orm.SkinnyCRUDMapper

case class Type (id: Option[Long], typeName: String)

object Type extends SkinnyCRUDMapper[Type] {
  override def defaultAlias = createAlias("t")
  override def columnNames = Seq("id", "type_name")
  override def extract (rs: WrappedResultSet, n: ResultName[Type]): Type = new Type(
    id = rs.get(n.id),
    typeName = rs.get(n.typeName)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining belongsTo/byDefault relationship to typeWine and extracting typeWine value with its resultName should work for you.